# In Azure, can I call a Python script from my C# WebJob?

Tags: c#, python, azure, azure-webjobs

I want to create a WebJob in C#. Unfortunately, I need to use a Python 3 script as there is currently no suitable library for 1 particular task that I need to perform, using C#.

For example, see this [answer/example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33004907/596841).

Is it possible to have my WebJob call a Python script? I can place the Python3 script in a blob container - would I then be able to call and execute it from my C# WebJob?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it's possible to call a Python 3 script via C# WebJob that follow the [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33004907/596841) you linked. First of all, you need to install a Python 3 runtime as below.

1. Access the kudu tool via the url `https://<your webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`, and follow the figure below to install a Python 3 runtime. 
   [image]
2. For example to install `Python 3.5.2 x86`, it will be installed in the path `D:\home\Python35`, then you just need to change the Python execute file path in the sample to try to run it.

Hope it helps.

---

**Update**: Install `pip` tool & other Python packages.

1. Access the url `https://<your azure webapp name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`.
2. Commands as below.

   ```
   D:\home>cd Python35
   D:\home\Python35>curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
     % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

   100 1558k  100 1558k    0     0  6829k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 7179k
   D:\home\Python35>python get-pip.py
   Requirement already up-to-date: pip in d:\home\python35\lib\site-packages
   Collecting wheel
     Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
   Installing collected packages: wheel
   Successfully installed wheel-0.29.0
   ```
3. For example, install `numpy` package

   ```
   D:\home\Python35>python get-pip.py numpy
   Collecting numpy
     Downloading numpy-1.13.1-cp35-none-win32.whl (6.8MB)
   Installing collected packages: numpy
   Successfully installed numpy-1.13.1
   ```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have other python libraries being used by my script (the script uses NetCDF4, for example)?

Comment: @pookie First, you need to download [`get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) script file to install `pip` tool in the python runtime path. Then, you can use `Scripts/pip install <package name>` to install the packages you need.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't fully understand. I am familiar with pip and installing packages, but I am not sure how to execute my `Scripts/pip install <package name>` command. I'm also not sure what you mean by `install pip tool in the python runtime path` - will that `get-pip.py` do that for me?

For example, I can't install `get-pip.py` via the kudu tool. What do I do with this file?

Comment: @pookie I updated my reply for how to install pip & use it to install more packages.

Comment: @PeterPan Do you mind taking a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830172/path-to-execute-python-script-from-azure-webjob)? I assume the path is not set correctly.

Comment: @bbusdriver I will try to help you to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is the best approach but this is what I did in the past:

- Create a python webjob (manual, triggered) ([see tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2016/12/09/running-python-webjob-on-azure-app-services-using-non-default-python-version/))
  [image: Create Azure Webjob - Manual Triggered]
- Create a C# webjob.
- Trigger the Python job from the C# job:

  ```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
      var username = "jobusername";
      var password = "jobpassword";
      var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}");
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
      var response = await client.PostAsync("joburl", null);
  }
  ```

You can find the job credentials from the job properties on azure portal:
[image: Azure webjob properties]