# Webjobs Running Error (3587fd: ERR ) from zipfile

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have  the following small script in a file named `fgh.py` which I have been attempting to schedule as a webjob

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2],'b':[5,6,9]})

df['x']=df.a.sub(df.b)

print(df)
```

Using @Peter Pan [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57830172/running-python-script-from-azure-webjob). I have created a virtual environment, done a `pip install pandas`. From the virtual environment, the script runs and executes as required.It however does not execute when loaded in `Azure Webjobs`. I suspect issues arise from the interface between the run,bat file and the Azure python console but have limited understanding of Azure to resolve the issue

In kudus, I have used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008688/in-azure-can-i-call-a-python-script-from-my-c-sharp-webjob) to install python.

Running `where python` in  `cmd` command in `https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` I get;

[image]

Additionally from `https://arcgistrial.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` I get the following when I run cmd command `python -V`
[image]

In my `run.bat` file, I have tried to use either of the directories above without success.

Whether I make my `run.bat` file `D:\home\python364x64\python.exe fgh.py` or `D:python364x64\python.exe fgh.py` I get the following error;
[image]

I have gone a head and installed `pandas` and checked if successful by trying to install `numpy`
[image]

All this has not helped. I have been on this for a couple of days and it has to work somehow. Any help?

Comment: @Peter Pan what could I do different?

Comment: @Hopefully, I can get it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Things are not quite straightforward in old Webjobs to run python task with dependencies. It has been quite some time, the world has moved on to [Azure Function](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/functions/) :))

However, since you still need to stick to Webjobs, below are the steps I followed which worked. I am using a batch file (.cmd) to run the python script due to the pre-requisites.

1. By default webjob supports python 2.7 at this moment. So, add python3 from 'extension' in your web app, In this case it was 3.6.4 x64 for me. This will add in path `D:\home\python364x64\`. How did I know? Kudus console :)

[image]

2. Create a `requirements.txt` file which contains `pandas` and `numpy` (note I had to explicitly add numpy version 1.19.3 due to [an issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) with latest 1.19.4 in Windows host at the time of this writing). Basically I used your `fgh.py` which depends on `pandas` which in turn depends on `numpy`.

```
pandas==1.1.4
numpy==1.19.3
```

3. Create a `run.cmd` file having the following content. Note 1st line is not needed. I was just checking python version.

```
D:\home\python364x64\python --version
D:\home\python364x64\python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
D:\home\python364x64\python -m pip install --user certifi
D:\home\python364x64\python -m pip install --user virtualenv
D:\home\python364x64\python -m virtualenv .venv
.venv\Scripts\pip install -r requirements.txt
.venv\Scripts\python fgh.py
```

4. Zip `fgh.py`, `run.bat` and the `requirements.txt` files into a single zip. Below is the content of my zip.

[image]

5. Upload the zip for the webjob.
6. Run the job :)

[image]
[image]

Ignore the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'", not needed.

Answer (score -1):

***The key to solving the problem is that you need to create your venv environment on azure.***

Step 1. Run successfully in local.

[image]

Step 2. Compress your webjob file.

[image]

Step 3. Upload webjob zip file.

**Because the test environment has python1 before, I will create a webjob of python2 later.**

[image]

[image]

Step 4. Log in kudu.

① `cd ..`
[image]

② find Python34, click it.

[image]

③ `python -m venv D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\python2\myenv`

[image]

④ Find myenv folder.

[image]

⑤ active myenv, input `.\activate.bat`.

> D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\python2\myenv\Scripts>.\activate.bat

[image]

⑥ Back to python2 folder, and input `pip install pandas`.

[image]

⑦ Then input `python aa.py`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have run through... How do I then get the wbjo going in the app? Went to check and there is no webjob created.

Comment: You need to create webjob first(step3).

Comment: And if have something wrong, you also need add `import sys
sys.path.append('D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\App_Data\\jobs\\continuous\\python2\\myenv')` in your code, to use myenv.

Comment: I think Microsoft officials still have problems with these details. We need to try. All operations are the results of our tests. If you have more questions, you can raise a support ticket for help.

Comment: There are only so many attempts we developers can do.

Comment: Do you mind sharing logs in the python app window after it executed?

Comment: I also can saw the error msg. You need to find way to active myenv and use it.

Comment: I am searching the ways to help you.

Comment: So it was not executed in the app?

Comment: Yes，we just can run scripts in kudu. That donnot we want.

Comment: I was after execution in the webapp as webjobs, that what is expected of me