# Is there a way to deploy a Python code in Azure and run it in webjob?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

I have a Python code and received specific instructions saying 'deploy it in Azure and run the job'. Could anyone help me understand the same? I have access to the Blob storage (from where the code is picking the input files and is uploading the output), as well as to Azure Devops.
PS- Non technical person here so would appreciate any help on that.

Thank you

Comment: You can do it using Azure DevOps.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python-webapp?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 1):

#### The workaround follows:

#### Create a python Script

Create a python Script (fileName.py)

```py
import sys  
print(sys.version)  
print("our test web job running....")
```

After creating the file run locally.

#### Make a .Zip file of python script and required folders

[image]

#### Deploy web jobs in Azure App Service

In your **AppService -> Settings Blade ->** Select **Web Jobs** **->
Add** your Web Job Application

[image]

[image]

Go to the **Logs** it will show the details of web job information

[image]

#### Reference:

- Adding Realtime [Web Jobs Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57850103/15997690) in Azure
- [Steps to Add web Jobs in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64549879/15997690)